# PyQT open another ui and sent some text

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qt-designer

I have two `UI` forms from `QTDesigne`r. `ParentUI` open `ChildUI` and must add text from `parentUI.QTExtEdit` to `ChildUi.QListWidget`. I wrote function in `ChildUI` which add lines to `ListWidget`, but it doesn't correct run from `ParentUI`. If I try to add lines from `ParentUI`: `self.child_win.listWidget.addItem('popka')`, I take the same result.

Here is my Parent window:

```
<pre>
<code>
<!-- language: python -->

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from list import Ui_List

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Sender_edit(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Sender_edit):
        Sender_edit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Sender_edit"))
        Sender_edit.resize(400, 154)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Sender_edit)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Sender_edit)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Sender_edit)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Sender_edit)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Sender_edit)

    def retranslateUi(self, Sender_edit):
        Sender_edit.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Sender_edit", "Sender_edit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Sender_edit", "ok", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.send_info)

    def send_info(self):
        sender = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        print(sender + "  lalka")
        self.showChildWindow()

    def showChildWindow(self):
        self.child_win = Ui_List()
        self.child_win.listWidget.addItem('popka')
        self.child_win.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Sender_edit()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

</code>
</pre>
```

And child window:

```
<pre>
<code>
<!-- language: python -->

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_List(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setupUi(self)
    def setupUi(self, List):
        List.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("List"))
        List.resize(400, 154)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(List)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(List)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(List)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(List)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        self.retranslateUi(List)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(List)


    def retranslateUi(self, List):
        List.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("List", "LIST", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("List", "Fucking_edit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("List", "Close", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
#        self.add_lines('fuck')

    def add_lines(self, line):
        self.listWidget.addItem(line)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_List()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

</code>
</pre>
```

How can I send info from one window to another?

Thanks in advance=_)

Comment: Works fine for me: I click "ok", new window appears with line "popka". You call `setupUi` twice in Ui_List,  just a copy paste error ?

Comment: @tmoreau Yes, it's my error, sorry. I changed qlistwidget to qtextedit, and all work. But with QListWidget the problem unchanged. I have one more question, maybe you can suggest something. How to send signal or run function from child to parent, in my program? I tried import, but it's impossible)

Comment: If the child emit a signal, you connect to it on the parent side. For example for a button on the child window: `self.child_win.button.clicked.connect(some parent function)`

Comment: @tmoreau I tried do like this: `self.child_win = Ui_List() self.child_win.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.printui)` in parent's code, but when I push, nothing happens. I something wrong understood maybe?

Comment: My guess: you created `child_win` twice. Once you created it in `showChildWindow`, there's no need to do `self.child_win=Ui_List()` again. If that's not it and you can't figure it out, you can open a new question.